# Image not showing in table cell using FPDF and Easy table

Tags: fpdf

I am building an FPDF document which forms a contract and is working ok and to help with the layout i am using easytable.  on the document I capture a signature and then save it in to a folder called signatures and give it the persons name.

The problem is trying to display the signature in a table cell using the php variable.  I have an example which shows how to do it, if it is a static image.

```
   $table1->easyCell('', 'img:Pics/fpdf.png, w80; align:R;');
```

Now to try and use the variable which i get through a post request i have tried writing it like this, however this just creates a 500 error along with any other variant i can think of.

```
   $table1->easyCell('', 'img:signatures/'$name'.png, w80; align:R;');
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to solve it, i thought i had already tried writing it like this, but guess i hadn't.  The signature image now displays perfectly

```
  $table1->easyCell('', 'img:signatures/'.$name.'.png, w80; align:R;');
```